# what is the method that help me to automatically create document in mongodb collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I am building a MEAN stack application, i need my system to automatically create a document in Attendances collection every starting day.
is that possible and if yes how can i do it? please help me with this.

Comment: First, you need to write the javascript code that creates the document. Once that is working you need to schedule that code to run once per day. On linux and mac look at the crontab command line command. On windows look into the Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a cron job in your NodeJS application, which will get trigger every day and create/add a document to your MongoDB collection.

Or if you are using MongoDB Atlas for MongoDB server, checkout Scheduled triggers - https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/triggers/scheduled-triggers/